# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException in springmodule.xml file due to '&' in DB password

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven, xml-parsing

I am getting below error in springmodule.xml file

**Line 128 in XML document from class path resource [springmodule.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 128; columnNumber: 50; The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.**

this is because my DB password contain '&' sign.
I got this same error in pom.xml file so replace '&' with '`&amp;` but in xml file how to replace the same.

can we use any string function here to replace '&' with `&amp;`?

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="${DB_URL}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${DB_USER}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${DB_PASS}"/>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Do not use the old outdated xml configuration for spring. Use the more modern java configuration

Comment: Have you tries to use `&amp;` for the password? this shud be substituted to `&` by the xml parser

Comment: password is stored in variable DB_PASS which is being fetched from other source

Comment: In a nutshell, you are saying , for the bean to be able to load the property value , it reads an XML document, the easiest would be to use &amp in the XML doc value and filter the property (replace) of any XML character entities in get or set !

Comment: Writing a bean helper method to convert XML element values with XML entities (for illegal XML characters) back to natural string form inside set or get is more sensible than writing an XSLT for each element to retrieve by mapping  and flagging to convert the entities in the value to a property of a bean.

Comment: XML entities are case sensitive,  checking with if() using stringval.indexOf() would make a helper method easy to use with stringval.replaceAll()

Comment: Spring replaces the value while reading so the XML parser shouldn't see the `&` at all. So unless you are using processing to replace the values the `${}` shoul sbe handled by Spring and you shouldn't have any issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works for me:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="${DB_URL}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${DB_USER}"/>
        <property name="password">
        <value><![CDATA[${DB_PASS}]]></value>
    </property>
    </bean>
```